# SQL : getting a value according to the minimum date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

In the following example I would like to get the status value according to the minimum date:

```
 instId: status : instDate
 25478 : 5      : 18/02/16 13:32:14
 25478 : 3      : 18/02/16 13:32:05
 25478 : 1      : 18/02/16 13:32:11
 69854 : 9      : 18/02/16 16:22:10
 69854 : 5      : 18/02/16 16:22:26
 69854 : 4      : 18/02/16 16:22:15
```

The output would be

```
25478 : 3
69854 : 9
```

**Edited:**
I was doing like this but it seems not working

```
select instId, MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY instDate DESC NULLS LAST) STATUS
from sales
group by instId;
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *minimum* date, then order by `ASC` rather than `DESC`:

```
select instId,
       MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY instDate ASC NULLS LAST) as STATUS
       -----------------------------------------------------^
from sales
group by instId;
```

I have found that this is often faster than the `row_number()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT instId, status
FROM (
        SELECT instId, status, 
               row_number() over (partition by instId
                                  order by date) as rn
        FROM YourTable
     ) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

But this can cause a problem if two rows have same date and different status. You will get a status a random between the ties rows.